# PostgreSQL: How to dump raw index data

Tags: postgresql

I'm curious if there's a way to inspect the raw data stored in the index? How would the PostgreSQL developers debug index content? A few Google searches only seem to return information largely on dumping the whole DB *with* indices, presumably just for backups, which I'm assuming would just be represented as SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the [pageinspect](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html) extension to examine B-tree indexes.

With `bt_metap()` you get the meta-page of the index, which gives you the root page. With `bt_page_items()`, you can examine the raw data in an arbitrary index page.